# Is it possible to use other personalisation string than what in Profile Management in Triggered Emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm very new to Exact Target. And I want to send the transactional email using the REST API (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html). But when I create the Triggered Emails with the email template that has personalisation string that not in Profile Management, it showed an error.

Is there any workaround that makes this process possible? Or I have to add every merge tags in transactional emails to Profile Management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use triggered emails you should create a triggered data extension (you can select it from DE's templates). Then this DE should be assigned into the triggered email settings. In this way every DE's field could be use as dynamic variables inside the HTML Code of the email.